# Convertir fecha de xml a json para guardar en mongodb

Tags: c#, xml, mongodb

Buenas tardes. Actualmente tengo un *XML* en donde tengo varios datos, uno de ellos es una fecha. Con la ayuda de *C#* obtengo esa fecha y después la requiero insertar en mongodb con formato `date`.

Le fecha me llega así:

```
<FechaVencimiento>2024-01-01T00:00:00</FechaVencimiento>
```

Espero haber sido claro y me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Primero usa el Nuget Packager para bajar el paquete "newtonsoft json.net"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego es tan facil como las siguientes 3 lineas de codigo:

```
XmlDocument documento = new XmlDocument();
documento.LoadXml(xml);
string miJson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(documento);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho